# Will sinners be in hellfire forever considering God's characteristics of not keeping angry forever?

Tags: forgiveness

Jeremiah 3:12 MEV

> Go and proclaim these words toward the north, and say: Return, backsliding Israel, says the LORD, and **I will not cause My anger to fall on you. For I am merciful, says the LORD, and *I will not keep anger forever*.**

Psalm 103:9 MEV

> He will not always accuse, **neither will He keep his anger forever**.

Psalm 85:5 MEV

> Will You be angry with us forever? Will You draw out Your anger to all generations?

Comment: The three texts you quote refer to those who _repent_ of their backsliding and who _repent_ of their making God angry. _Gehenna_ (eternal hellfire) is the inevitable consequence to those who do not repent. No other alternative is available.

Comment: See Jude 7 - Sodom and Gomorrah are not still burning

Comment: @Dottard - Jude verse 7 does not say that the physical locations of Sodom and Gomorrah are still burning. Rather, Jude says the inhabitants "serve as an example of those who suffer the punishment of eternal fire". The physical body perishes, but that is not the end of the soul. There is still a final day of reckoning (Revelation 20:14-15).

Comment: @Lesley - agreed!  But the point remains that the cities (the inhabitants are not mentioned specifically, only the cities) are the example of eternal fire.

Comment: When Jude verse says "Sodom and Gomorrah and the surrounding towns gave themselves up sexual immorality and perversion" he was referring to the inhabitants, the people. I must disagree with your view that "the inhabitants are not mentioned specifically".

Comment: "They serve as an example of those who suffer the punishment of eternal fire" speaks of the wicked inhabitants, not the bricks and mortar of physical towns. This is a clear warning about the eternal state. Even Jesus warned us time and again of the wrath to come.

Comment: @Lesley The "eternal fire" is God.  See Deuteronomy 4:24 and Hebrews 12:29.  God is eternal, and is a consuming fire.  Sodom and Gomorrha and all their inhabitants were destroyed by God, i.e by "eternal fire."  Note that Jude 7 mentions "the _vengeance_ of eternal fire."  Beings or persons have "vengeance," not inanimate things like fire.  As God has said, "Vengeance is mine."  See Romans 12:19; Deuteronomy 32:35.

Answer (score 3):

The divine nature is such that no attribute of God contradicts another one. Sadly, some people take the idea that "God is love" to mean he would never punish anyone in hell (whether that be an eternal punishment, or mere 'soul annihilation'). They do not seem to take into account other facts, such as God is righteous (*Jehovah Tsidkenu* means God righteousness is - Jeremiah 23:6) and that "our God consuming fire is he" -Deuteronomy 4:24 (as quoted in Hebrews 12:29).

All three combine. "God love is" - 1 John 4:16 - and there is only one way of love entering the being of humanity, as stated in Romans 5:1-9 - as a freely given gift to all who hear the gospel by faith, for:

> "Being justified by faith, we have peace with God through our Lord
> Jesus Christ... the love of God is shed abroad in our hearts by the
> Holy Spirit which is given unto us... But God commendeth his love
> toward us in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us. Much
> more then, being now justified by his blood,  we shall be saved from
> wrath through him." (KJV)

This is what the gospel of Christ is all about - God's love demonstrated in Christ; God's righteousness demonstrated at Golgotha when sin was justly dealt with; God's wrath poured out righteously on all who reject that provision of being saved from our sins. As stated in Romans 1:16-18 -

> "For I am not ashamed of the gospel of Christ, for it is the power of
> God unto salvation to every one that believeth: to the Jew first and
> also to the Greek, for therein is the righteousness of God revealed
> from faith to faith as it is written, 'The just shall live by faith'.
> For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness
> and unrighteousness of men, who hold the truth in unrighteousness."
> (KJV)

This means that those who reject the righteousness of God reject the gospel, which is the power of God to salvation - from his righteous wrath. There are many men who take the gospel, but hold that truth in unrighteousness. And they have many followers who like to hear certain things about God, but not other things. There are many who like to think that they merit righteousness due to what they do, instead of confessing God's righteousness in condemning all sin as unrighteousness. And we are all sinners who deserve nothing but the wrath of God.

This means that those who would judge God as being unrighteous to punish sinners who reject his gospel of grace, are going to suffer eternal fire, for "God consuming fire is". Yet those who submit to the refining fire of God will be cleansed and live, while those who object to the very idea will cry out, as did Isaiah, "Who can dwell with everlasting burnings?" They will have to, for there is no alternative for those who reject God's righteous provision of saving sinners from the wrath to come.

***Answer in Summary:*** ***None of those three texts you cite has any bearing on eternal hellfire as the punishment for unrepentant sinners***, for those three texts address repentant sinners whom God will lovingly and freely forgive. Those are the ones who discover the anger of God removed from them. Therefore, **unrepentant sinners will forever have to live with the fact that they rejected the righteousness of God.** "Everlasting burnings" indeed! Burning with shame and guilt when if they had humbled themselves under God's mighty hand at hearing the gospel of salvation, they could have been freely delivered from deserved punishment as rebels against their Creator.

EDIT in view of a comment that claimed, "Read Isaiah 33. Only the righteous get to live in the "everlasting burnings." No. the context is Isaiah warning sinners in Zion:

> "The sinners in Zion are afraid; fearfulness has surprised the
> hypocrites. Who among us shall dwell with the devouring fire? Who
> among us shall dwell with everlasting burnings?
>
> He that walketh righteously, and speaketh uprightly; he that despiseth
> the gain of oppressions, that shaketh his hands from holding of
> bribes; that stoppeth his ears from hearingh of bnlood, and shutteth
> his eyes from seeing evil: He shall dwell on high... Thine eye shall
> see the king in his beauty." (Isaiah 33:14-17 KJV)

Those who have no fear of the Lord, who do not humble themselves under his righteous judgments and repent (because they twist or reject the gospel of salvation) shall have to dwell with God's everlasting burnings of judgment, but not so the others, who will be on high and behold the King in his beauty.

Comment: Teachings of eternal suffering are symbolic, not literal. Only a sadist would create such a reality for nothing little mortals.

Comment: "*For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.*" — The contrast is between "perish" and "everlasting life", not between "good everlasting life" and "bad everlasting life". The central message of Christianity is forgiveness, not vindictiveness, and God sets the example.  Satan would have people believe otherwise.

Comment: 'unrepentant sinners will forever have to live' no, only the righteous are given eternal life. Your complete premise based on an unbiblical immortal soul is the error here. The stubbornly unrepentant will forever die - that is what the second death is for.

Comment: @kjw47 - Jesus talked more about the eternal destination of those who reject him than any other Bible writer. Why all his warnings about eternal suffering if it isn't true? Was he just trying to scare people?

Comment: @RayButterworth 'Satan would have people believe otherwise'. No wonder so many have rejected the bible and trusted instead the human doctrines of immortal souls, eternal torment and another Jesus. Thankfully some get it - usually they stand out by the downvotes.

Comment: Up-voted +1. Competent excellence. This is what SE-BH is here for. Much appreciated.